# How to open a file in the project as a stream?

Tags: c#, windows-8, resources, xna, monogame

I have a collection of text files in my project containing level information that I want to load as streams and read in XNA. I am using MonoGame XNA and targeting Windows RT. Let's say I want to open /Content/Levels/Level1.txt as a stream. How would I do this?

On some other platforms using C# I would set the file's build action to resource and use

```
Application.GetResourceStream
```

but this is not available in XNA.

Comment: Is using `using (var fs = new Filestream(path))` an option?

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199094.aspx

Comment: @user1306322 No, there is no FileStream class in the System.IO Namespace.

Comment: @JP Alioto That works great. If you change it to an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Okay, I'll blow it out into more of a real answer, but glad that helps! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of storage in an XNA game: Title Storage and User Storage.  See [What is Storage?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200105.aspx)  To read data from Title Storage, use [TitleContainer.OpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.openstream.aspx) as in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199094.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = "Dummy.xml";
string resourceName = "Namespace0.Folder.Folder2.DataFolder." + fileName;
 

var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```